# Why is doesn't my content fill the full width in devtools responsive size

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

When visiting [www.felkru.com](https://www.felkru.com) and opening it in chrome devtools after resizing the window in responsive mode a bar appears on the right side of my content.The error also occures when zooming out on iOS. In Firefox, after following the same steps, no bar appears. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the picture. `width: 100vw` and `padding` section `.about`

solution:

```
section {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

or

```
#portrait {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -0.3em;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```